# How can I get the ggplot2 boxplot to have y-axis range showing only up to the ends of the whiskers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, I would like the boxplot to have y-axis range spanning to just the ends of the whiskers so that the plot does not include all of the outliers, but without making all of the outliers invisible. So basically, I would like to go from the first image [boxplot with y range including all outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKX0Z.png) to the second image [boxplot with y range to widest point of whiskers but while showing some outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3HA.png)

This is the code I have currently, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to do. Any ideas?

```R
get_range <- function(data, j) {
  split_dfs <- group_split(data, group)
  ends <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(split_dfs), ncol = 2))
  colnames(ends) <- c("min_range", "max_range")
  for (i in c(1:length(split_dfs))) {
    cur_min <- min(split_dfs[[i]][, j + 2])
    cur_max <- max(split_dfs[[i]][, j + 2])
    i_summary <- (split_dfs[[i]])[, j + 2] %>%
      pull() %>%
      quantile()
    Q1 <- i_summary[["25%"]]
    Q3 <- i_summary[["75%"]]
    iqr <- (split_dfs[[i]])[, j + 2] %>%
      pull() %>%
      IQR()
    ends[i, "min_range"] <- Q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    ends[i, "max_range"] <- Q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
  }
  y_min <- min(ends$min_range)
  y_max <- max(ends$max_range)
  return(list(y_min, y_max))
}


plot_features <- function(data, i) {
  lims <- get_range(data, i)
  lim_min <- lims[[1]]
  lim_max <- lims[[2]]
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = data[, i + 2], fill = group)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(lim_min, lim_max)) +
    ylab(colnames(data)[i + 2]) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x=element_blank())
}
```

Comment: from what I get your code is doing, it assigns the min/max range of your groups to a list, you then assign this to `coord_cartesian(ylim = ....)`.  Check what your `get_range()` returns, if your limits are not what you expect.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be best if your question included a [minimal data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that allows people to run your code.